# convert To Text to To Number Crystal Report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

how to convert to text to currency or number?

```
ToText(Sum ({tblGLTransactionDet.mDebit_amt}, {tblGLAccount.sAccount_cd}) - Sum ({tblGLTransactionDet.mCredit_amt}, {tblGLAccount.sAccount_cd}),2)+"Dr."
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `ToNumber()`

Depending on what values are possible for your field, I recommend also doing a check to see if it even *can* be converted to a number:

```
IF NumericText({field}) THEN ToNumber({field}) ELSE 0
```